# Group by id and create a column based on priority in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Can someone help me with the below.
I have an input dataframe.

| ID | process_type | STP_stagewise |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | loan_creation | Manual |
| 1 | loan creation | NSTP |
| 1 | reimbursement | STP |
| 2 | loan_creation | STP |
| 2 | reimbursement | NSTP |
| 3 | loan_creation | Manual |
| 3 | loan_creation | STP |
| 4 | loan_creation | Manual |
| 4 | loan_creation | NSTP |

Output dataframe required:

| ID | process_type | STP_stagewise | STP_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | loan_creation | Manual | Manual |
| 1 | loan creation | NSTP | Manual |
| 1 | reimbursement | STP | STP |
| 2 | loan_creation | STP | STP |
| 2 | reimbursement | NSTP | NSTP |
| 3 | loan_creation | Manual | Manual |
| 3 | loan_creation | STP | Manual |
| 4 | loan_creation | NSTP | NSTP |
| 4 | loan_creation | NSTP | NSTP |

I need to groupby id and process_type column and prioritize, Manual >> NSTP >> STP and create a different column.

Can someone provide an approach to solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Slight change along with ID, group by should be done on process type also.

Comment: If those 3 are the ONLY possible values, "Manual >> NSTP >> STP" is coincidently in alphabetical order.   That means, you can take the minimum value of `STP_stagewise` per ID. `df.withColumn('STP_type', F.min('STP_stagewise').over(Window.partitionBy('ID')))`.  

If you have other values that interfere the order, you need to convert it to integer then do the window function.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can solve this is by aggregating at `id` and collecting all the distinct `STP_stagewise` into a list and sorting it with a `custom_sort_map` to get the first index element and finally joining it back to your main DataFrame

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
ID  STP_stagewise
1   Manual
1   NSTP
1   STP
2   STP
2   NSTP
3   Manual
3   STP
4   Manual
4   NSTP
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='\t')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------------+
| ID|STP_stagewise|
+---+-------------+
|  1|       Manual|
|  1|         NSTP|
|  1|          STP|
|  2|          STP|
|  2|         NSTP|
|  3|       Manual|
|  3|          STP|
|  4|       Manual|
|  4|         NSTP|
+---+-------------+
```

#### Aggregation - Collect Set & Sort

```
custom_sort_map = {'Manual':0,'NSTP':1,'STP':2}

udf_custom_sort = F.udf(lambda x: sorted(x,key=lambda x:custom_sort_map[x]), ArrayType(StringType()))

stpAgg = sparkDF.groupBy(F.col('ID')).agg(F.collect_set(F.col('STP_stagewise')).alias('STP_stagewise_set'))\
                .withColumn('sorted_STP_stagewise_set',udf_custom_sort('STP_stagewise_set'))\
                .withColumn('STP_type',F.col('sorted_STP_stagewise_set').getItem(0))

stpAgg.show()

+---+-------------------+------------------------+--------+
| ID|  STP_stagewise_set|sorted_STP_stagewise_set|STP_type|
+---+-------------------+------------------------+--------+
|  1|[STP, NSTP, Manual]|     [Manual, NSTP, STP]|  Manual|
|  3|      [STP, Manual]|           [Manual, STP]|  Manual|
|  2|        [STP, NSTP]|             [NSTP, STP]|    NSTP|
|  4|     [NSTP, Manual]|          [Manual, NSTP]|  Manual|
+---+-------------------+------------------------+--------+
```

#### Join

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.join(stpAgg
                       ,sparkDF['ID'] == stpAgg['ID']
                       ,'inner'
                      ).select(sparkDF['*'],stpAgg['STP_type'])

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------------+--------+
| ID|STP_stagewise|STP_type|
+---+-------------+--------+
|  1|       Manual|  Manual|
|  1|         NSTP|  Manual|
|  1|          STP|  Manual|
|  3|       Manual|  Manual|
|  3|          STP|  Manual|
|  2|          STP|    NSTP|
|  2|         NSTP|    NSTP|
|  4|       Manual|  Manual|
|  4|         NSTP|  Manual|
+---+-------------+--------+
```